# Is there a way to pre-filter events (for a specific event name) for end users without involving them (no checkboxes or dropdowns) (JSON feed)

Tags: filter, fullcalendar, server-side, fullcalendar-3

(Hello all. This is my first post using the guided posting mode, so please bear with me)

I have been using Fullcalendar for a little while now to display events from JSON feeds for multiple calendars (One calendar per JSON feed). These JSON feeds are conversions of .ics feeds by ical.js to work fullcalendar. However, I now have need to break these calendars down into lists and filter them based on certain text in the event names in a manner similar to this:

Full event list.

```
January 1
   lunch
   gathering
   outing
   dinner
January 2
   lunch
   gathering
   outing
   dinner
January 3
   lunch
   closing
```

filtered event list for webpage (filtered for lunch).

```
January 1
   lunch
January 2
   lunch
January 3
   lunch
```

Can I filter based on event title with Fullcalendar when the calendar is based on a feed and not a manual list of events?

I am running fullcalendar 3.9.0 (I may move to 3.10). It is the most current version I can run due to other software needing to be configured to work with version 4.

I am also employing the mozilla ical.js script to convert ical feeds into JSON feeds.

My expectation is that I may actually have two areas in which I could possibly filter:

1. within ical.js or ical_events.js
2. within my configuration for fullcalendar (maybe in the defaultView section)

Here is a portion of code I use to call up a calendar:

```
ics_sources = [
  {
    url:'https://www.example.com/calendaring/15/',
    event_properties: {
      color:'#7a9b49'
    }
  },
]

function data_req (url, callback) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.addEventListener('load', callback)
    req.open('GET', url)
    req.send()
}

function add_recur_events() {
    if (sources_to_load_cnt < 1) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', expand_recur_events)
    } else {
        setTimeout(add_recur_events, 30)
    }
}

function load_ics(ics){
    data_req(ics.url, function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', fc_events(this.response, ics.event_properties))
        sources_to_load_cnt -= 1
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''         
        },
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
            parent.setIframeHeight(iframeId) ;
        },
        eventClick: function(event) { 
          window.open(event.url,);
          return false;
        },
        defaultView: $(window).width() < 765 ? 'listYear':'listYear', 
        nowIndicator: false, 
        eventLimit: 4, 
        fixedWeekCount: false, 
        listDayFormat: 'MMMM Do',
        listDayAltFormat: false,
        noEventsMessage: "No Currently Scheduled Events"
    })

    sources_to_load_cnt = ics_sources.length
    for (ics of ics_sources) {
        load_ics(ics)
    }
    add_recur_events()
})
```

Expected (desired) results would be a list pre-filtered in the calendar call based on the desired event title for the end user.

Actual results: I currently do not have any pre-filtering going on.

Comment: to be clear...are you using ical.js on the server side? Is your server side node.js? It would be more efficient to filter the data on the server if you can...once you've got ical.js to create the JSON, then you could write some code to filter the list before you return it to the client. Obviously you'd need to have passed the user's selected filter word as a parameter in your AJAX request.

Comment: P.S. your way of defining and fetching the event sources is very cumbersome, and unnecessary - fullCalendar can take care of this for you, including handling all the AJAX requests. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources (and also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object)

Comment: Thanks ADyson, I do not have access to the server. I am using ical.js on my webhost on the page where the calendar display exists only. This is not the same server where the .ics feed actually exists. There is an iCal service that comes out of that other server as a calendar feed which can only be as granular as to list all the events of a specific group: Example: /location/group/events. Maybe there is a better way to make this work, but my methods were based on suggestions of others since I am not fluent in fullcalendar.

Comment: I'll look into what JSON ical.js is producing for filtering possibilities. Thanks

Comment: ok well you can do exactly the same filtering on the client-side, although it's slighly less efficient as you have to download everything, only to discard some of it. Within the fullCalendar context you have a couple of options for tapping into the event feed. You could handle [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) and check the content of each event against the filter criteria...if it doesn't match then you can return false, which (as per the docs) will discard the event from fullCalendar.

Comment: or you can implement the [events-as-function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) pattern for your event sources - whereby you retain the code for doing the AJAX requests, but when you get the response from the server you apply the filter criteria and remove any events you don't want, before then passing the final dataset to fullCalendar via the provided callback.

Comment: Thanks again ADyson, I will definitely look into the docs on these. I appreciate your time.

Comment: P.S. I just realised you are using v3 of fullCalendar. Sometimes the documentation can be different - v3 and v4 are quite different. All of the links I provided above are for v4...but if you look in the top right corner of each page you can load the v3 documentation instead which will be correct for your situation